# Why is hadoop fs -chmod useless?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, chmod

This is the result of using it:

```
$ hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive/
$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/
Found 1 items
drwxrwx--x+  - hive hive          0 2021-08-05 14:21 /user/hive/warehouse
```

As can be seen, it doesn't do a thing, the mod of /user/hive is still 775. Why this could happen and how to fix it?

Comment: As per the Hadoop 3.3.1 documentation: "The user must be the owner of the file, or else a super-user." https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Comment: Wow, not even emitting a single warning message, how was this design adopted?

Answer (score 0):

Is Sentry enabled on this cluster? By the permissions on the warehouse folder,  I suspect Sentry is there, and if it is, Sentry provides the permissions.

You may see an warning in the NN logs indicating the command was ignored.